# Querying the N firsts and M last documents in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Everything is in the question : I don't find an efficient way to return the first and the two last documents of my query...

I pass in parameters and array containing the requireed _id, that I select with `{ parentPost: { $in: myArray } }`, but I don't figure out how to get both the two lasts and the first document in the same query...

The goal would be to return a collection of documents containing all the wanted posts of each thread (identified by parentPost) in a single query I can return in one subscription.

Could someone lighten my path ?

Thank you

David

Comment: I think you would need to use two separate queries to do this.  Sorting is required for limiting to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I assume each post in an separate doc, and there are other fields in that upon which we can filter, like `name`.
Let's start with a 2 query example just to "get it done."   Assuming something in docs is sortable like post number or a datetime field, then this clearly works.

```
c = db.foo.find({"name": "matt"}).sort({"post":1}).limit(N);
c.forEach(function(r) { printjson(r); });
c = db.foo.find({"name": "matt"}).sort({"post":-1}).limit(M);
c.forEach(function(r) { printjson(r); });
```

Of course, if you don't have a sortable thing, just go based on natural on-disk ordering:

```
c = db.foo.find({"name": "matt"}).sort({"$natural":1}).limit(N);
c.forEach(function(r) { printjson(r); });
c = db.foo.find({"name": "matt"}).sort({"$natural":-1}).limit(M);
c.forEach(function(r) { printjson(r); });
```

Here is a variation.  It is likely faster because it avoids sorting twice only to restrict the output to just a few things:

```
n = db.foo.find({"name": "matt"}).count();
c = db.foo.find({
    "name": "matt",
    "$or": [
      {"post": {$lte: N}}
      ,{"post": {$gte: n-M}}
            ]
     });
```

Comment: The problem is that as I want all those document returned in a publish function and available in a single collection on client-side, I guess I only can return a cursor from one query to deal with my collection client side ?

How could I do that ?